# Integrating JSR-356 WebSocket @ServerEndpoint with Spring 3 beans

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-3, jsr356

I'm using Spring 3.2.5 without full new JSR-356 WebSockets support.

I would like to have singleton-bean reference in my `@ServerEndpoint` WebSocket server, which is instantiated by servlet container itself, not in Spring context.

**What is the clean way to do it?**

My current solution: I made `@Service` singleton bean with instance in static field:

```
@Service
public class WebSocketSupportBean {
    private volatile static WebSocketSupportBean instance = null;

    public static WebSocketSupportBean getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public WebSocketSupportBean() {
        instance = this;
    }
```

and just getting it in `@ServerEndpoint` by static method, disconnecting user if null returned (if bean not jet created during server startup but user connects):

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can setup websockets with spring framework 3.x

I developed a small proof-of-concept application to demonstrate how, based on Rossen Stoyanchev's SpringConfiguration released with spring-core 4.0.

The application sets up a websocket server endpoint with uri `/wstest` which will use a `@Autowired` spring bean to select a greeting word and reply to a websocket message.

The websocket connection is initiated and messages sent by an html page (`index.html`) running in a browser that supports websockets.

The Endpoint registration is made by a ServletContextListener at context initialization and when the endpoint is instantiated it will be wired with spring:

```
@WebListener
public class MyApplication implements ServletContextListener {

    private final static String SERVER_CONTAINER_ATTRIBUTE = "javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer";

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        ServletContext container = sce.getServletContext();

        final ServerContainer serverContainer = (ServerContainer) container.getAttribute(SERVER_CONTAINER_ATTRIBUTE);
        try {
            serverContainer.addEndpoint(new MyEndpointConfig(MyEndpoint.class, "/wstest"));
        } catch (DeploymentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the Endpoint is:

```
@Component
public class MyEndpoint extends Endpoint {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {

        session.addMessageHandler(new MyMessageHandler(session));
    }


    class MyMessageHandler implements MessageHandler.Whole<String> {

        final Session session;

        public MyMessageHandler(Session session) {
            this.session = session;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String message) {
            try {
                String greeting = myService.getGreeting();
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText(greeting + ", got your message (" + message + "). Thanks ! (session: " + session.getId() + ")");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Checkout the full source and ready to run example on my [Github page](https://github.com/cemartins/websocket-test).

Comment: Great example! As a good practice, I would enclose the cast to (ServerContainer) in the try catch too. I (lazily) copied your snippet and was having a completely silent class cast exception while deploying on Tomcat due to dependency problems. It took me a couple hours to find the problem.

Comment: can you help to check my question in github. there may exist bug in this code

Answer (score 2):

You have to add bean definition in the configuration of spring.

The solution i found to integrate JSR 356 websocket `@ServerEndpoint` is to turn off the  Servlet container's scan for WebSocket endpoints by spring which can be done by registering @Bean in your Spring Configuration. By this spring not overrides normal JSR 356 websocket by spring STOMP websocket which is the part of the websocket.

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/chatMessage")
public class ChatEndpoint{
// Normal websocket body goes here.
}
```

Adding Beans in your Configuration as:

```
@Configuration
public class WebsocketConfig{
  @Bean
  public ChatEndpoint chatEndpoint(){
     return new ChatEndpoint();
  }
  // main one is ServerEndpointExporter which prevents Servlet container's scan for WebSocket
  @Bean
  public ServerEndpointExporter endpointExporter(){
     return new ServerEndpointExporter();
  }
}
```

This all done for you. But you should remove `configurator = SpringConfigurator.class` from `@ServerEndpoint`.
I am using Spring Websocket 4.0.0 and it works fine.
You can also see this [Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/server/standard/ServerEndpointExporter.html).

If you alright then follow this [Link](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/adding-websocket-endpoints-on-the-fly-with-jrebel-and-spring-boot/) also for concept.

Note that, Normally you should make websocket configuration separately from the main configuration of your spring.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
```

And add maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: spring-websocket is post 4.0, not spring 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your @ServerEndpoint object extend SpringBeanAutowiringSupport. Then just make it aware of beans that gets constructed within a Spring-based web application this way:

```
  @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }
```

This way @Autowired annotation will worl correctly:

```
@Autowired MyService myService;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,it works for me

```
@Component
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/instantMessageServer",configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
public class InstantMessageServer{
private static IChatService chatService;
    @Autowired
    public InstantMessageServer(IChatService chatService){
        this.chatService = chatService;
    }
    public InstantMessageServer(){}
}
```

I found this solution on https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support
but there is one more glitch,the class annotated with @ServerEndpoint cant acquire httpsession with SpringConfigurator,there is no a override of method modifyhandler in it.Maybe we create a seperate Configurator extends SpringConfigurator and override that method would be a workaroud.
It is better to build a real-time web application with spring-websocket and messaging api,I think.

---

```
public class ModifiedServerEndpointConfigurator extends SpringConfigurator{
    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig sec, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response) {
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) request.getHttpSession();
        sec.getUserProperties().put(HttpSession.class.getName(),httpSession);
        super.modifyHandshake(sec, request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know whether there are more bugs in the future.