# @ServerEndpoint and @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, websocket, autowired

How can I autowire a field into a @ServerEndpoint. The following does not work.

```
@Component
@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class MyWebSocket {   
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
}
```

However if I remove the `@ServerEndpoint`, it works fine.

I am using spring 3.2.1 and Java 7

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: objectMapper is null. It is not injected/autowired

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to integrate Spring and Java WebSocket API. A class annotated by `@Component` is registered to a spring bean and its instance is managed by spring as a singleton by default. However, a class annotated by `@ServerEndpoint` is registered to a server-side WebSocket endpoint and every time the corresponding endpoint's WebSocket is connected to the server, its instance is created and managed by JWA implementation. Therefore, you can't use both annotations together.

Maybe the simplest workaround is to use CDI instead of Spring. Of course, your server should support CDI.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class MyWebSocket {   
    @Inject
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
}
```

If it's not feasible to you, you can intercept instantiation process of the class annotated with `ServerEndpoint` by using a your own version of [ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/server/ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.html). Then, you can instantiate the class by yourself and autowire it using an instance of `BeanFactory` or `ApplicationContext`. Actually, there is already similar answer to this usage. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435622/integrating-jsr-356-websocket-serverendpoint-with-spring-3-beans) and Martins' [working example](https://github.com/cemartins/websocket-test) (Especially, a customized [Configurator](https://github.com/cemartins/websocket-test/blob/master/websocket-server%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Forg%2Fjuffrou%2Ftest%2Fwebsocket%2FSpringConfigurator.java) for integration with Spring).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very helpful. Though I just went ahead after updating to Spring 4 which has its own WebSocket impementation classes

Answer (score 6):

This issue could be fixed using SpringConfigurator (spring 4):

Add configurator to your ServerEndpoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
```

required maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to just add this to your class actually.:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
}
```

Comment: That line worked if I added it my constructor, but not a postConstruct, which is not called by my javax websocket.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:

```
public WebsocketServletTest() {
      SpringApplicationListener.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
}
```

where SpringApplicationListener is a ApplicationContextAware, which stores the context in a static variable

Answer (score 0):

JavaEE 7 specification says

```
@ServerEndpoint
The annotated class must have a public no-arg constructor.
```

Comment: I did not show in sample but there is already a default constructor in the class.