# Springboot @ServerEndPoint "Failed to find the root WebApplicationContext."

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-boot, jsr356

**I'm having trouble using spring with @ServerEndPoint annotated class**

i'm using Springboot 1.2.3 and i'm trying to figure it out how to have a single instance of the endpoint

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableWebSocket
public class ApplicationServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfigurator {

    @Bean
    public ServerEndPoint serverEndpoint() {
        return new ServerEndPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter() {
        return new ServerEndpointExporter();
    }
}
```

WebSocket endpoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/", decoders = MessageDecoder.class, 
encoders = MessageEncoder.class, configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
public class ServerEndPoint {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerEndPoint.class);

    public static final Set<CommunicationObserver> OBSERVERS = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, Message msg) {
        LOG.debug("Received msg {} from {}", msg, session.getId());
        for (CommunicationObserver o : OBSERVERS) {
            o.packetReceived(session, msg);
        }
    }
```

This is based on the [Spring WebSocket JSR-356 tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support), but i've got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to find the root WebApplicationContext. Was ContextLoaderListener not used?
    at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.SpringConfigurator.getEndpointInstance(SpringConfigurator.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointServer.onOpen(PojoEndpointServer.java:50)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have both tested in embedded mode and with external tomcat 8 and jetty 9 (in external mode, i remove de Spring config file) but the same error appeares.

[the only workaround i've found is to create a custom configurator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306854/serverendpoint-and-autowired)

```
public class SpringEndpointConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator {

    private static WebApplicationContext wac;

    public SpringEndpointConfigurator() {
    }

    public SpringEndpointConfigurator(WebApplicationContext wac) {
        SpringEndpointConfigurator.wac = wac;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T getEndpointInstance(Class<T> endpointClass) throws InstantiationException {
        T endPoint = wac.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().getBean(endpointClass);
        return (endPoint != null) ? endPoint : wac.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(endpointClass);
    }
```

it is created as a @Bean with the parameterized constructor.

I must have missed something to get it done with the SpringConfigurator class, but i don't know what.

Comment: Instead of following that tutorial I suggest [this one](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) as that is tailored for Spring Boot instead of plain spring.

Comment: this tutorial is using STOMP protocol, i have to stick with plaintext websocket because we use a custom protocol. or am i missing something ?

Comment: might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158106/websocket-with-sockjs-spring-4-but-without-stomp/27161986#27161986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to Sergi Almar and [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27158106/websocket-with-sockjs-spring-4-but-without-stomp/27161986#27161986), i have managed to use the Spring implementation instead of the javax.websocket implementation:

```
public class SpringWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private final Set<CommunicationObserver> observers = Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();

    @Autowired
    private MessageContext mc;

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        Message msg = mc.parse(message.getPayload());

        for (CommunicationObserver o : observers) {
            o.packetReceived(session, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Config file:

```
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfigurator implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myHandler(), "/").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringWebSocketHandler myHandler() {
        return new SpringWebSocketHandler();
    }
}
```

Note that the setAllowedOrigins("*") was mandatory for me because when using the java client, i had the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils : Failed to parse Origin header value [localhost:8080]
```

Also note that the MessageContext was used to parse/format strings instead of MessageEncoder/Decoder classes (they inherited from MessageContext).

Answer (score 9):

`SpringConfigurator` uses `ContextLoader` to obtain spring context. Spring Boot does set up the ServletContext but it never uses `ContextLoaderListener` which initializes `ContextLoader` to hold static state of spring context. You can try to add `ContextLoaderListener` or as a workaround you can write your own context holder and configurator.

Here is an example:

First context holder and configurator:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpointConfig;

public class CustomSpringConfigurator extends ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator implements ApplicationContextAware {

    /**
     * Spring application context.
     */
    private static volatile BeanFactory context;

    @Override
    public <T> T getEndpointInstance(Class<T> clazz) throws InstantiationException {
        return context.getBean(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        CustomSpringConfigurator.context = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

To get context we need to configure this as Bean:

```
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfigurator {

...

    @Bean
    public CustomSpringConfigurator customSpringConfigurator() {
        return new CustomSpringConfigurator(); // This is just to get context
    }
}
```

Then you need to set configurator correctly:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/", decoders = MessageDecoder.class, 
encoders = MessageEncoder.class, configurator = CustomSpringConfigurator.class)
public class ServerEndPoint {
...
}
```

As a side note, yes if you delete `SpringConfigurator` your application will start and you can handle request. But you cannot autowire other beans.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing, but thanks a lot, it works for me

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot the Spring context is not loaded via `SpringContextLoaderListener` which is required by the `SpringConfigurator.class`.

Thats why the endpoints and and `ServerEndpointExporter` beans are needed.

The only thing you have to do to get your example working is removing the `SpringConfigurator.class` from the `@ServerEndPoint` endpoint definition.

Comment: thanks for the reply but what i wanted was to have a single instance of the ServerEndPoint. With the ServerEndpointExporter, there is a new instance on every incoming socket connexion.

Comment: how the endpoint is registered in ServerEndpointExporter and how to use it... I not understand about that in https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/server/standard/SpringConfigurator.html . Would you kindly give me example.