# Java Spring-boot - How to use @Autowired with @ServerEndpoint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, java-websocket

I know there are lot of questions on this topic. I have read the spring boot doc and all of the solutions here. According spring boot doc, `@ServerEndpoint` is a Javax annotation and `@Autowired` components are spring-boot managed. These two cannot be used together. The solution to this would be to add `SpringConfigurator` as configurator of the `ServerEndpoint`. When I tried this I do get the following error:

> Failed to find the root WebApplicationContext. Was ContextLoaderListener not used?

There is no example in the spring-boot websocket [page](https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support) to use `ContextLoaderListener`. How can use `ContextLoaderListener` so that components can be injected into `@ServerEndpoint` annotated controllers?

The following is my code.

Websocket controller

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/call-stream", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
public class CallStreamWebSocketController
{  
    @Autowired
    private IntelligentResponseService responseServiceFacade;

    // Other methods
}
```

Websocket configurations

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public CallStreamWebSocketController callStreamWebSocketController()
    {
        return new CallStreamWebSocketController();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter()
    {
        return new ServerEndpointExporter();
    }
}
```

Edit:
This has been tagged as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306854/serverendpoint-and-autowired) question. I have tried the solution specified in the answers. The solution is to add `SpringConfigurator` as configurator of the `@ServerEndpoint`. After adding this I still do get the error mentioned in the details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@ServerEndpoint and @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306854/serverendpoint-and-autowired)

Comment: I have referred that question. It says (like the spring boot doc) to add `SpringConfigurator` as the `@ServerEndpoint` configurator. As I have clearly said in the question, this does not work.

Comment: Did you add the mentioned spring-websocket dependency to the classpath?

Comment: I am using spring-boot not spring. So I added `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket` to my classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found a way to force spring-boot to inject a component into an externally managed/instantiated class.

1) Add a generic method to your class extending `ApplicationContextAware` to return a bean.

```
@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        SpringContext.context = context;
    }

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    // Generic method to return a beanClass
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass)
    {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
}
```

2) Use this method to initialize the class object you want to be injected

```
private IntelligentResponseService responseServiceFacade = SpringContext.getBean(IntelligentResponseService.class);
```

So after the above changes my websocket controller would look like this

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/call-stream", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
public class CallStreamWebSocketController
{  
    private IntelligentResponseService responseServiceFacade = SpringContext.getBean(IntelligentResponseService.class);

    // Other methods
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works. There are some incompatibility issues with spring boot dependency injection and JSR356 annotation.

Comment: This results in a null pointer exception on SpringContext.context